# Trying to add a legend in the left upper corner of the graph, but the code I've taken from other scripts isn't working

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I want to add a legend of my two data sets in the upper left corner of my plot, but somehow the code that I've taken from other scripts isn't working does anybody have an idea why?

```
library("ggplot2")
library("reshape2")

data<-read.csv("trial.csv",header=TRUE,dec=".",sep=',',na.strings="NA")

#Example of data
Year Annual Cumulative
1  1960      1          1
2  1961      0          1
3  1962      0          1
4  1963      0          1
5  1964      0          1
6  1965      0          1
7  1966      0          1
8  1967      1          2
9  1968      0          2
10 1969      0          2
11 1970      0          2
12 1971      0          2
13 1972      1          3
14 1973      0          3
15 1974      1          4
16 1975      1          5
17 1976      0          5
18 1977      0          5
19 1978      0          5
20 1979      4          9
21 1980      2         11
22 1981      1         12
23 1982      1         13
24 1983      3         16
25 1984      1         17
26 1985      2         19
27 1986      1         20
28 1987      4         24
29 1988      3         27
30 1989      3         30
31 1990      3         33
32 1991      1         34
33 1992      4         38
34 1993      0         38
35 1994      4         42
36 1995      4         46
37 1996      3         49
38 1997      5         54
39 1998      2         56
40 1999      0         56
41 2000      6         62
42 2001     11         73
43 2002      8         81
44 2003      2         83
45 2004      5         88
46 2005      7         95
47 2006     13        108
48 2007     22        130
49 2008     13        143
50 2009     13        156
51 2010     17        173
52 2011     14        187
53 2012     24        211
54 2013     24        235
55 2014     18        253
56 2015     19        272
57 2016     17        289
58 2017     16        305
59 2018     24        329
60 2019      9        338
```

Plotting code:

```
p1<-ggplot(data=data,aes(x=Year))+
  geom_line(aes(y=Cumulative),linetype="solid",color="red",size=1.1)+
  geom_point(aes(y=Cumulative),shape=1,color="red",size=3,stroke=1.5)+
  geom_line(aes(y=Annual),linetype="solid",color="darkorange",size=1.1)+
  geom_point(aes(y=Annual),shape=1,color="darkorange",size=3,stroke=1.5)+
  scale_y_continuous(sec.axis=sec_axis(~.*1/10,name="Annual\n"))
p1<-p1+labs(x="\nYear",y="Cumulative\n")
  p1+theme(axis.title.x=element_text(size=18),
           axis.text.x=element_text(size=14),
           axis.title.y=element_text(size=18),
           axis.text.y=element_text(size=14),
           axis.ticks=element_blank())
```

Comment: With neither your data nor your current output, we can't recreate the chart and can't see it. I don't see anything here that sets the position of the legend

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of alternative ways to do this. One quick thing to do is melt the data by year and simplify geom_point and geom_line to remove some repetition. You will have a legend created for you, which you can customize and relocate based on legend.position in your theme.

```
library("ggplot2")
library("reshape2")

data.melt <- melt(data, "Year")
ggplot(data.melt, aes(x = Year, y = value, color = variable)) +
  geom_point(shape=1, size=3, stroke=1.5) +
  geom_line(linetype="solid", size=1.1) +
  scale_colour_manual(values=c("darkorange", "red")) +
  scale_y_continuous(sec.axis=sec_axis(~.*1/10, name="Annual\n")) +
  labs(x="\nYear", y="Cumulative\n", color="Legend Title") +
  theme(axis.title.x=element_text(size=18),
         axis.text.x=element_text(size=14),
         axis.title.y=element_text(size=18),
         axis.text.y=element_text(size=14),
         axis.ticks=element_blank(),
         legend.position = c(0.1, 0.9))
```